# Norway raster layer - Hybrid solution

Tags: openstreetmap, tilemill

I am new to OSM and I would like you to help me with some questions I have.
I'm styling my raster map of Europe.

The data for the raster I have obtained from srtm.csi.cgiar.org but the data for Norway, Sweden does not appear and I would like to obtain them. So I have obtained them from land.copernicus.eu.

Once all the data has been obtained, I have tried to make a hybrid solution to add this information, but on the one hand the data is stepped on since there is a small common area of ​​both in the downloaded data.

Is there any way so that the information for the common area of ​​Norway does not appear double or is there somewhere where I can download all the data for the raster of the map of Europe that will quickly load the map and thus not have to do a hybrid solution with information from two sites? I've tried downloading everything from Copernicus and it slows down and doesn't even load the map.

[image]

Comment: Please refrain from reposting closed questions. Instead concentrate on improving the existing question. Thank you.

Comment: Not this duplicate are different questions